# In Angular, how can I use template content inside a customer component or directive?

Tags: angular

Let's assume I have a component that needs to wrap around different sets of content:

`<div class="box-box"> ... content ... </div>`

Instead of having the component on a template and passing in an input to the child I want do something like:

`<my-big-box> ... content ... </my-big-box>`
or
`<div myBigBox> ... content ... </div>`

The former is preferred. I see something similar done with angular components such as `ng-content` or material ui components. Not sure 100% how that's achieved or what "terms" to use to get a better understanding.

Any push in the correct direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<ng-content>` to project HTML content into a custom component.

Assuming this is your component's template:

```html
<!-- 'section' and it's value can be anything you like, 
  you will use that to reference the ng-content  -->
<div class="box-box">
  <ng-content select="[section=header]"></ng-content>

  <!-- you can have an ng-content without  -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <p>
    This it's Box Box
  </p>
  <ng-content select="[section=footer]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then you can project content inside of it like:

```html
<my-big-box>
  <h3 section="footer">this should be in the footer</h3>
  <h1>this it's inside ng-content</h1>
  <h3 section="header">this should be in the header</h3>
</my-big-box>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qk57hy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[Angular's Content Projection documentation](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)